How to communicate between the host and a WebContainer?
I have a use case where I would like my main application to call API endpoints exposed by the application running within the WebContainer (https://webcontainers.io/) and vice versa. When my host server is running locally at localhost:3000 and I call fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/...") from within the WebContainer, obviously it doesn't work, because that API endpoint does not exist within the container.
I already thought of a few rather "hacky" solutions, such as:

Writing a file to the WebContainer's file system whenever I want to communicate with it, and polling for changes within the WebContainer.
Using some sort of reverse proxy (e.g. ngrok), so that e.g. "myapp.example.com" is forwarded to my host application running on localhost, and then I could just fetch "myapp.example.com" from within the WebContainer. I already tried it out and this does actually work using ngrok, but it feels much more complicated than necessary.

But there must be a better solution for this kind of basic HTTP communication between host and container. How do I do this?
